# Could not Detect Online Connectivity in Angular 11

Tags: angular11

I tried to show online status in angular 11.
I did same as like this https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-detect-the-internet-connection-status-in-an

My ts.file

```
import { ConnectionService } from 'ng-connection-service';

  isConnected = true;  
  noInternetConnection: boolean; 

 constructor(private connectionService: ConnectionService,) {

    this.connectionService.monitor().subscribe(isConnected => {  
      this.isConnected = isConnected;  
      if (this.isConnected) {  
        this.noInternetConnection=false; 
      }  
      else {  
        this.noInternetConnection=true;
      }  
      
    })  
  }
```

my.html file

```
  <nb-action *ngIf="noInternetConnection">
      <p>online</p>
    </nb-action>
    <nb-action *ngIf="!noInternetConnection">
      <p>offline</p>
    </nb-action>
```

**BUT it shows offline. MY wifi connection is on**

Can anyone help me to find the bug?

Comment: I found my mistake in my html code. It sholud be 

    `<nb-action *ngIf="noInternetConnection">
      <p>offline</p>
    </nb-action>
    <nb-action *ngIf="!noInternetConnection">
      <p>online</p>
    </nb-action>`

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't recommend to use another library to listen for native browser events as this makes the application more robust, and probably the library does the same as the following code :(

When I achived such functionality I created event listeners for the native "online" and "offline" events.

Here is the network monitor service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class NetworkStatusService {

  private init: boolean = navigator.onLine;
  private online: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject();

  get initStatus() {
    return this.init
  }
  constructor() {
    if (this.init==false) {
      this.online.next(false);
    }
    fromEvent(window, "online").subscribe((val) => {
      this.online.next(true);
    })

    fromEvent(window, "offline").subscribe((val) => {
      this.online.next(false);
    })
  }

  getOnlineStatus() {
    return this.online.pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. But i found my mistake. So i don't try you codes. Thank you